# mysqldump command not returning any data

Tags: mysql

I'm running this command `mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -d db_name -e --skip-add-drop-table --quick --skip-lock-tables >> /tmp/db1.sql`

But when I do a load this file locally to my mysql server, I don't get any data in my folder. I'm not sure which of these flags is causing that to happen, because all they seem to be doing is skipping dropping the tables before hand, locking the tables, and retrieving rows from the table one row at a time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does root@localhost not have a password? (no `-p` flag)

Comment: And just to be clear, if you login `mysql -uroot db_name` does the database contain anything?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski -- no password configured and yes if I login with that command it does contain data.

Comment: Do you have permission to create a new file in `/tmp` (seems unlikely you would not be able to)?  If you run `mysqldump` without redirection `>> /tmp/db1.sql` do you get output to your terminal?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. That -d flag I thought was for database actually means no data...

Comment: Ah, `-D` is the database name. More commonly, I supply the database as the last argument, after all flag args.

Comment: Long option names are recommended to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -d flag actually means no data, not specifying the database.